# Api policy to call api running on Azure container app from APIM using its user assigned identity

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, azure-container-apps

Api is running on Azure container app with user assigned identity uai_1. Apim is running with user assigned identity uai_2. I have setup the api policy (see the code below) so that apim can call api, is it correct way? I have not secured api in any way - any guidance on that would be appreciated like create a azure ad app registration for api etc. - not sure.

```
<policies>
  <inbound>
    <authentication-managed-identity resource="client id of user assigned identity uai_1" client-id="client id of user assigned identity uai_2" ignore-error="false"/>  
  </inbound>
</policies>
```

This is what the docs say https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/authentication-managed-identity-policy

Comment: You would need to protect your container app using azure ad auth: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/authentication then grant permission to the managed identtiy

Comment: More or less the same as you would do with a webapp

Comment: thanks. I have a simple hello world react webapp running on aca. I have enabled easy auth on it using the same link that you have shared. I can sign into it. From this webapp, i am making a api call to APIM which should go to my simple python api running on aca. 
I understood from your comment that i should enable easy auth on api as well. And should look at client-directed flow or client flow and see how apim can complete this flow. Is it correct?

Comment: yeah sounds correct.

Comment: you could always pass the user token down to aca. how do the users authenticate to apim ?

Comment: ok so you just need outh between apim and the backend apis.

Answer (score 0):

The api policy to authenticate apim using its user assigned identity with backend api which is protected by azure ad or easy auth:

```
<inbound>
        <cors allow-credentials="true"> 
            <allowed-origins> 
                <origin>the origin url of web app</origin> 
            </allowed-origins> 
            <allowed-methods preflight-result-max-age="300"> 
                <method>*</method> 
            </allowed-methods> 
            <allowed-headers> 
                <header>*</header> 
            </allowed-headers> 
            <expose-headers> 
            <header>*</header> 
            </expose-headers> 
        </cors>
        <authentication-managed-identity resource="b147569f-643a-4d3b-b0e4-55750750f770" client-id="e880ad99-c842-49ee-9d71-5f51e40c8a08" output-token-variable-name="msi-access-token" ignore-error="false"/>
            <set-header name="Authorization" exists-action="override">
                <value>@("Bearer " + (string)context.Variables["msi-access-token"])</value>
            </set-header> 
</inbound>
```

In the above example, b147569f-643a-4d3b-b0e4-55750750f770 is the `client_id` of backend api azure ad app

e880ad99-c842-49ee-9d71-5f51e40c8a08 is the `client_id` of apim uai